# Phenomena in the intersection of general relativity and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, black-holes

I am looking for physical phenomena that have aspects involving both general relativity and quantum mechanics.

The only example I know is Hawking radiation. While black holes are objects that cannot be described in Newtonian gravity - only in general relativity, creation of virtual particle pairs is a purely quantum mechanical phenomenon.

What other phenomena require both quantum mechanics and general relativity to treat properly?

Comment: I know one: gravity-induced quantum interference, see Sakurai-Modern Quantum Mechanics p147

Comment: Thanks, does it require GR - specific effects or Newtonian gravity explains it as well?

Comment: You mean, something like [this?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4307)

Comment: @Alex Nelson, thanks for the link. Looks like besides Hawking radiation we have no phenomenons I am looking for.

Comment: @Haolin Lu, thanks for mentioning, however gravity-induced interference does not require GR to be involved.